# App Id (team id)

Tags: ios, icloud, app-id

My question is that all my app ids are the same.  I think they are supposed to be different as to identify them.  Even when I try to create a new profile it does not give me the option to change the Id or generate a new one.  I am trying to set up ICloud for one of my apps and i believe this is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App IDs are managed in the Apple developer portal under "Identifiers".
You would need to create a new app ID here, then use that app ID to create your new profile.

You should not have multiple apps using the same app ID.